# Verifica a existência de um vértice em R

Tags: r, grafo

Estou usando igraph no R. Tenho o seguinte grafo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma função no R, que me retorne um valor booleano, que verifique a existência de um vértice?

Answer (score 1):

A pergunta está um pouco mal definida, mas seria isto que tu tá procurando?

```
library(igraph)

g <- graph.full(n=10) # cria grafo completo, com 10 vertices

V(g) # 10 vertices numerados de 1 a 10

TRUE %in% (V(g) == 1) # o vertice 1 estah neste grafo?
[1] TRUE

TRUE %in% sum(V(g) == 15) # o vertice 15 estah neste grafo?
[1] FALSE
```